# Fileconveyor Error - UnboundLocalError: local variable 'classname' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, fileconveyor

I am using fileconvayor form  https://github.com/wimleers/fileconveyor

but when I run the script I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "arbitrator.py", line 1185, in <module>
run_file_conveyor()
File "arbitrator.py", line 1168, in run_file_conveyor
arbitrator = Arbitrator(os.path.join(FILE_CONVEYOR_PATH, "config.xml"), rest
art)
File "arbitrator.py", line 142, in __init__
transporter_class = self._import_transporter(transporter_name)
File "arbitrator.py", line 1162, in _import_transporter
self.logger.error("The Transporter module '%s' was found, but its Transporte
r class '%s' could not be found."  % (module_name, classname))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'classname' referenced before assignment
[root@af-server fileconveyor]#
```

Here is the code from   arbitrator.py  line 142

```
   # Verify that all referenced transporters are available.
    transporters_not_found = 0
    for server in self.config.servers.keys():
        transporter_name = self.config.servers[server]["transporter"]
        transporter_class = self._import_transporter(transporter_name)
        if not transporter_class:
            transporters_not_found += 1
    if transporters_not_found > 0:
        raise TransporterAvailabilityTestError("Consult the log file for details")
```

and the code from line 1162

```
transporter_class = None
    module = None
    alternatives = [transporter]
    default_prefix = 'transporters.transporter_' # Not  'fileconveyor.transporters.transporter_'!
    if not transporter.startswith(default_prefix):
        alternatives.append('%s%s' % (default_prefix, transporter))
    for module_name in alternatives:
        try:
            module = __import__(module_name, globals(), locals(), ["TRANSPORTER_CLASS"], -1)
        except ImportError:
            pass
    if not module:
        msg = "The transporter module '%s' could not be found." % transporter
        if len(alternatives) > 1:
            msg = '%s Tried (%s)' % (msg, ', '.join(alternatives))
        self.logger.error(msg)
    else:
        try:
            classname = module.TRANSPORTER_CLASS
            module = __import__(module_name, globals(), locals(), [classname])
            transporter_class = getattr(module, classname)
        except AttributeError:
            self.logger.error("The Transporter module '%s' was found, but its Transporter class '%s' could not be found."  % (module_name, classname))
    return transporter_class
```

Here is whole code form that file

http://pastebin.com/ctsLrckq

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when I installed fileconveyor followed the guide INSTALL.txt.
It looks like there are some unresolved dependencies. Try solve it with:

`pip install django-cumulus==1.0.10`

Answer (score 0):

The exception is catching an error two lines earlier than you thought: it is coming in the `classname = module.TRANSPORTER_CLASS`. Whatever `module` is, it doesn't have a TRANSPORTER_CLASS`attribute, so an exception is raised and`classname` is never defined. If you weren't swallowing the actual error message, that would be clear.

I must say though that this code makes very little sense. In that `else` clause you already have `module`, so why are you reimporting it on the following line?

Comment: If he entered the second `try` clause, then `module is None`. Note what the first `try` clause does.

Comment: @Reef, no: the second `try` is in the `else` clause of `if not module`, so if he's in there, he *has* a module.

Comment: You are right. This code makes very little sense :)

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
classname = module.TRANSPORTER_CLASS
```

throws an `AttributeError` exception, because `module` doesn't have a `TRANSPORTER_CLASS` attribute. This causes the interpreter to jump to the `self.logger.error(...)` line **before** the `classname` variable is defined. Formatting the log string fails when the logger line tries to use the undefined variable. In order to fix it, you could replace the logger line with this one:

```
self.logger.error("The Transporter module '%s' was found, but its Transporter class could not be found."  % (module_name,))
```

Please note that `__import__` can raise `ImportError`, which is not catched. I guess the author of this code meant to catch it.

Comment: When I replace this line I get this error Last login: Mon Mar 31 
    File "arbitrator.py", line 142, in __init__
    transporter_class = self._import_transporter(transporter_name)
    File "arbitrator.py", line 1162, in _import_transporter
    self.logger.error("The Transporter module '%s' was found, but its    Transporte
     r class '%s' could not be found."  % (module_name))
     TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
     [root@af-server fileconveyor]#

Comment: That's because you missed the `,` just after `module_name` and before the `))`. Just copy the whole line.